# No module named 'lxml' Windows 8.1

Tags: python, windows, lxml

Everyone's code online refers to `sudo apt-get #whatever#` but windows doesn't have that feature. I heard of something called Powershell but I opened it and have no idea what it is.

I just want to get a simple environment going and lxml so I could scrape from websites.

Comment: A significant portion of developers use Linux or OS X these days. `sudo apt-get whatever` would be the command you use for some Linux based OSes. However Python installs `pip` which should let you type in almost the same command across Windows/OS X/Linux.

Comment: For scraping try using [beautifulsoup 4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), its tailor made for that purpose. You have an option to use `lxml` as the xml parser in beautifulsoup if you want to. I have a nasty feeling the `lxml` will want to compile some c code, which you may not be set up to do. If you are happy to give `beautifulsoup` a whirl just type `pip install beautifulsoup4`.

Comment: If you opened Powershell and didn't recognize it as a command-line terminal, I'd suggest starting with a computing class before going into programming.

Comment: @PaulRooney BeautifulSoup 4 is working fine, so I'm just gonna use that now. Thanks!

Comment: No probs. Glad to help.

Answer (score 4):

Go to the regular command prompt and try `pip install lxml`. If that doesn't work, remove and reinstall python. You'll get a list of check marks during installation, make sure you check pip and try `pip install lxml` again afterwards.

`pip` stands for pip installs packages, and it can install some useful python packages for you.

Comment: I type in `pip install lxml` and I get an error
`Collecting lxml
  
    ERROR: b"'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
    ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **
    
    running build_ext
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
    
    ----------------------------------------
`

Answer (score 4):

Try downloading the `lxml` package from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml), then, on the command prompt, type in:

```
pip install path/to/lxml_package_file
```

For example, after downloading `lxml‑3.5.0‑cp35‑none‑win_amd64.whl` since I have Python 3.5 on a 64-bit Windows box, I type in the following commands:

```
cd path/to/lxml_file
pip install lxml‑3.5.0‑cp35‑none‑win_amd64.whl
```

Then it should install fine.

Answer (score 0):

Other packages may be used instead:

import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree

import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

import cElementTree as etree

import elementtree.ElementTree as etree

[The lxml.etree Tutorial](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html)